# Importing a CSV file and reading specific lines VB.NET ASPX ASP.NET SQL DATATABLE

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable

Essentially i want to import a csv file which contains data that should be stored in a datatable and then into SQL. I want to also check if the all the required columns are entered into the csv file before importing to the datatable

How can i go about doing this ?

Thanks

Comment: Please note that StackOverflow is not a coding service.

Answer (score -1):

Read all lines into variable, if you have a header as first line of CSV, parse it and create datatable columns and next you can simply add new rows into datatable.
If you need, specify a divider.

```
Dim FileToExtract as FileInfo = nothing; 'load a file info    
Dim CSVDivider As String = ";"
Dim EncodingType As Encoding = Nothing
Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(FileToExtract.FullName, If(EncodingType Is Nothing, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"), EncodingType))
Dim cols As String() = (New Regex(CSVDivider)).Split(lines.First)
             
For i As integer = 0 To cols.Length - 1
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(If(CSVTrim <> "", cols(i).Trim(CSVTrim), cols(i)), If(dtColumnsType IsNot Nothing, dtColumnsType.Item(cols(i).Trim(CSVTrim)), GetType(String))))
Next
        
For Each line In lines.Skip(1)
    Dim objFields = From field In (New Regex(CSVDivider)).Split(line)
                    Select If(CSVTrim <> "", field.Trim(CSVTrim), field)
    Dim newRow = dt.Rows.Add()
    newRow.ItemArray = objFields.ToArray()
Next
```